# Clicking sound when I apply pressure on brake

Tags: brakes, noise, suspension, clicking

When I am applying pressure to my brakes I hear a sound that can be described as a clicking one. It is very faint, have to listen keenly. There is no squeaking, grinding or any high pitched noises that might indicate that it has something to do with my brakes wearing down etc.(I could be wrong).

To add, at some random days, when I sit or get up or sit in my vehicle I would hear a creaking/groaning noise. This was happening before the clicking noise. In some cases when I would rock the vehicle from the rear I would hear this same noise. As I stated before it is very random, a month will go by and I do not hear this creaking/groaning. Very intermittent.

What could be the possible causes? How serious of an issue are these factors likely to be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Some cars actually have this as a reminder, clicking noise when brakes are in need of maintenance. Or possibly a foreign object. There are a lot of possible reasons, more info needed to give an accurate opinion based on all of the facts.

Comment: @Goodoboy78 the brake pads were the issue. I went to someone other than the dealer where they saw something was wrong vs the dealer saying my brake pads were perfectly fine. Makes me question what is the point of my dealer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you might have 2 issues. The creaking could be bad strut(s) or worn control arm bushings. The clicking may be brake related or possibly something to do with suspension. Especially if you can feel the clicking in the steering wheel or on your butt from the seat.

Comment: It was brake related. Brake pads have been replaced. I went to someone other than the dealer where they saw something was wrong vs the dealer saying my brake pads were perfectly fine. Makes me question what is the point of my dealer.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it could be anything from a pebble caught in the tire tread to your wheel getting ready to fall of.

What I'd do:

1. Try to determine which end, front or back, the sound is coming from.  Enlist a helper to listen while you drive.
2. Try to determine which side, left or right.
3. Inspect that corner, take the wheel off, check the wheel and tire.  Inspect the brake components for wear or misalignment.  Inspect the wheel bearings.  Inspect the CV joints (if present) as well as suspension components.

Comment: An interesting thing I noticed so apparently I wasn't pulling my handbrake all the way up. I guess I only did it half way. Since correcting this I do not hear either sound anymore. Could that have been an underlying issue? Maybe just coincidence?